# Rebuild Parent->Child->GrandChild hierarchy with LINQ performance

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq, lambda

#### The problem

I have a hierarchy that I am pulling from the database and trying to restore using `LINQ`. When I run my `LINQ` query against the collections, it does not appear to be hitting my grand-child objects.

#### Object setup

The hierarchy of my objects is as follows

```
One Project -> Many Sections
One Section -> Many BidItems
One BidItem -> Many SubItems
```

They are all related through foreign keys in the database and mapped to my model objects. The following are simplified versions of the models.

### Models

```
public class Section
{
    public int SectionId { get; set; }

    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
}

public class BidItem
{
    public int BidItemId { get; set; }

    public int SectionId { get; set; }
}

public class SubItem
{
    public int SubItemId { get; set; }

    public int BidItemId { get; set; }
}
```

### View Models

```
public class SectionViewModel : BaseChangeNotify
{
    private readonly Section section;
    private readonly List<BidItemViewModel> bidItems;

    public SectionViewModel(Project project, Section section)
    {
        var repository = new ProjectRepository();

        this.section = section;

        this.bidItems = new List<BidItemViewModel>(
            (from item in repository.GetBidItemsBySectionId(section.SectionId)
             select new BidItemViewModel(project, item)).ToList());
    }

    public SectionViewModel(Project project, Section section, List<BidItemViewModel> bidItemsForSection)
    {
        this.section = section;
        this.bidItems = bidItemsForSection;
    }
}

public class BidItemViewModel : BaseChangeNotify
{
    private BidItem bidItem;

    private List<SubItem> subItems;

    public BidItemViewModel(Project project, BidItem bidItem, List<SubItem> subItems = null)
    {
        var repository = new ProjectRepository();

        this.bidItem = bidItem;

        if (subItems == null)
        {
            subItems = repository.GetSubItemsByBidItemId(bidItem.BidItemId);
        }

        this.subItems = subItems;
    }
}
```

You can see in one constructor in each view model, I was hitting a repository to fetch the children objects. I wanted to re-write it because it's not performing well. There could be a dozen `sections`, each with 100+ `BidItems`. Each `BidItem` can have 100+ `SubItems`. So for a project having 5 sections, I hit the database 50,000 times during the apps start up (takes about 2.9 seconds).

### Troublesome source code

I have refactored it so that I just make 3 calls, one to fetch all sections for a project, one for all `BidItems` in a project and one for all `SubItems` in a project. Now I need to reconstruct the hierarchy.

I tried using Lambda initially:

```
List<Section> projectSections =
    repository.GetSectionsByProjectId(ProjectId).Where(section => section.SectionId != 0).ToList();
List<BidItem> bidItemCollection = repository.GetBidItemsByProjectId(ProjectId);
List<SubItem> subItemCollection = repository.GetSubItemsByProjectId(ProjectId);

// After the database calls so I can test actual reconstruction performance.
timer.Start();

foreach (var sectionViewModel in projectSections.Select(section => new SectionViewModel(project, section)))
{
    Parallel.ForEach(bidItemCollection
        .Where(bidItem => bidItem.SectionId == sectionViewModel.SectionId), bidItem => 
        {
            var bidItemViewModel = new BidItemViewModel(project, bidItem,   
                subItemCollection.Where(subItem => subItem.BidItemId == bidItem.BidItemId).ToList());

            sectionViewModel.BidItems.Add(bidItemViewModel);
        });

    sectionViewModels.Add(sectionViewModel);
}
timer.Stop();
```

and this worked alright, but was slow. My original approach would take 2.9 seconds during start up to return all Sections, BidItems and SubItems. The Lambda took 2.3 seconds. I then tried a LINQ query.

```
List<Section> projectSections =
    repository.GetSectionsByProjectId(ProjectId).ToList();
List<BidItem> bidItemCollection = repository.GetBidItemsByProjectId(ProjectId);
List<SubItem> subItemCollection = repository.GetSubItemsByProjectId(ProjectId);
timer.Start();

sectionViewModels = new List<SectionViewModel>(
    from section in projectSections
    select new SectionViewModel(
        project,
        section,
        bidItemCollection.Where(c => c.SectionId == section.SectionId)
            .Select(
                bidItem =>
                    new BidItemViewModel(project, bidItem,
                        new List<SubItem>(
                            subItemCollection.Where(subItem => subItem.BidItemId == bidItem.BidItemId))))
            .ToList()));
timer.Stop();
```

This returned the fastest, at 0.3 seconds, but each of the BidItems contained an empty SubItem collection. For some reason, my SubItems were not populating the BidItem view model constructor like they should. I set a breakpoint within the `subItemCollection.Where()` lambda and it never gets hit.

I would really appreciate some guidance on what I am doing wrong with my LINQ. I'm a bit new to LINQ so I know I'm doing something wrong that is a simple fix.

#### Edit:

So it appears the issue was my LINQ query unit test was using the wrong stored procedure (as was my Lambda) to fetch SubItems resulting inn zero returns. I have fixed that and now I get back matching numbers on all three variations.

The interesting thing is the results now. The first approach, hitting the database 500 times takes 1.89 seconds. The Lambda takes 2.3 seconds to reconstruct with 3 database queries. The LINQ takes 0.70 seconds. My database query (with Dapper) takes 0.11 seconds for both Lambda and LINQ unit tests. So I have two questions now.

1. Why is the lambda so much slower?
2. Can I improve my LINQ query to run faster than the 0.6 seconds it's taking to set up 400 small (4-9 basic value type properties) objects?

Thanks in advance!

Johnathon.

Comment: btw, `readonly List<T>` is really not read only. It only prevent you from re-assigning value to it, but you can always `Clear` or `Add` item to it.

Comment: take a look to [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why is the lambda so much slower?

`projectSections.Select(section => new SectionViewModel(project, section))`

```
from section in projectSections
select new SectionViewModel(
    project,
    section,
    bidItemCollection.Where(...).ToList()
```

These two call the different constructor, hence the difference in the execution time.

As long as the logic and method is the same, both way of writing it should give the same result and at the same time. Because, the compiler generate the same IL.

## How can I optimize it?

Since I cannot do the benchmark on your machine, I'll just use general assumption.

- Usually performing the pull all the required data is better than pulling it multiple times.
  So I would avoid calling to `SectionViewModel.ctor(Project,Section)` and `BidItemViewModel.ctor(Project,BidItem)` as they will perform more queries in the database.

With that said, I would write my lambda as following : `//actually this is just your 3rd piece of code cleaned up`

```
sectionViewModels = new List<SectionViewModel>(
        projectSections.Select(
            s => new SectionViewModel(project, s, bidItemCollection.Where(b => b.SectionId == s.SectionId).Select(
                    b => new BidItemViewModel(project, b, subItemCollection.Where(si => si.BidItemId == b.BidItemId))))));
```

Also, for prettiness, I've changed the following contructors to avoid having `ToList` in middle of Lambda :

```
public class SectionViewModel
{
    private readonly Section section;
    private readonly List<BidItemViewModel> bidItems;

    public SectionViewModel(Project project, Section section, IEnumerable<BidItemViewModel> bidItemsForSection)
    {
        this.section = section;
        this.bidItems = bidItemsForSection.ToList();
    }
}

public class BidItemViewModel
{
    private BidItem bidItem;
    private List<SubItem> subItems;

    public BidItemViewModel(Project project, BidItem bidItem, IEnumerable<SubItem> subItems)
    {
        this.bidItem = bidItem;
        this.subItems = subItems.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Xiaoy312, I didn't realize I was using the wrong constructor! I made the constructor changes to IEnumerable and modified my LINQ query to match yours and my unit test time was cut in half from 750ms to 375ms. Very much appreciated!